# Websockets Max Buffer Size

Tags: java, websocket

Ive spent all day looking for a solution to be able to increase the buffer size of a websocket.  So far nothing I have found has worked.  At the moment my code is:

```
@OnOpen
public void open(Session session, EndpointConfig conf) {
    session.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(5242880);
    System.out.println("Server has been opened with max binary message buffer size of: "+session.getMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize());
}
```

However this outputs:

```
Server has been opened with max binary message buffer size of: 65536
```

Despite the fact I changed it on the line above.  I have tried many other solutions and have finally given up and decided to make a post after hours of work.

Thanks for your help! ~lava

Comment: What implementation are you using?

Comment: its using jetty and javax, both set it up and just javax handles the incoming traffic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it with the `@OnMessage` annotation, for a binary message it will be (you can verify with the variant that includes `session`):

```
@OnMessage(maxMessageSize = 5242880)    
public void onBinary(byte[] message, Session session)
{
    System.out.println("max size:" + session.getMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize());
}
```